# pros and cons of .htc file

Tags: css, html-components

What are pros and cons of using a .htc file in CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the Pros (there might be, I just don't know them). One of the Cons is that it can only be used in IE and is completely non-standard.

Answer (score 1):

Another con is that it looks like Internet Explorer 10 will [remove them](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in standards and quirks mode. You can still use them in IE 10 if you change the document mode to be IE 9 or earlier.

> Support for element behaviors has been removed in Windows Internet
>   Explorer 10 Consumer Preview standards and quirks modes for improved
>   interoperability and compliance with HTML5. This means elements
>   previously bound to Element Behaviors will be treated as generic
>   elements, just like in other browsers. This change can impact pages
>   written exclusively for Windows Internet Explorer or pages that use
>   browser sniffing to alter their behavior in Internet Explorer.